# VANET in OMNET++ and Veins: the beacon message? Vehicles and RSU coverage?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am working on Veins framework, inside OMNET++. I need to know:

1) If the beacon message sending by a vehicle also sent to the RSU?

2) The maximum number of vehicules covered by a RSU?

3) Which correct SUMO version that work correctly with VEINS version (Veins 2.0)?

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any wireless transmission is received by any node (car or RSU) in range. There is no upper limit to how many nodes can be in range (other than the physical limitation of how closely you can pack computers together). For information on how to download Veins (and which versions are compatible), please refer to http://veins.car2x.org/download/